# Back button on safari browser not working properly iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I have a functionality in my app to show google directions, for that I am using deep linking. It opens app if iOS app is available otherwise it opens in browser. It is working fine except back button in case of browser. It works perfectly fine for the first time but when I lock the phone and unlock it, it disappears. As shown in images attached. Please explain what could be the issue and what's the alternate to that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The back button does not persist when interruptions occur

Comment: So, what should I do? Like what's the alternative, because from browser user cannot go back to app.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blog](http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/10/having-safari-problems-with-ios-8-2-try-this/), some users who have updated the iOS version have discovered the Safari web browser no longer works as it should on their iPhone or iPad. There seems to be a few variations of Safari issues with iOS 8.2, but typically the problems manifest as an inability for Safari to launch or stay open, Safari becoming unresponsive to touch input, Safari loading blank pages, and the Safari search/URL bar becoming unworkable. You may try to reset Safari in iOS by clearing website data, cache, history, and cookies.